# How to create a gray overlay for a UIButton in touched state programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I would like to make a generic class that when tapped, makes the element grayish.

Facebook's app is the perfect example of what I want to achieve. All their links and images become gray when tapped.

[image]

I can only guess that they are subclassing [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton).

I have made my button's style `UIButtonTypeCustom` to get rid of the rounded border. Beyond this, I don't know how to have the gray overlay because I see no such property in the documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're using a WebView, which highlights touched links with that grayness.

Comment: I will need to simulate this WebView highlighting in my native code.

Comment: @JoJo: Refer to my answer. I have edited my answer. I think that would help you.

Comment: I like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309225/uibutton-wont-gray-out#6309314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple:

```
#define TAG_GRAYVIEW 5671263 // some random number

// add the gray overlay
UIView *grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:button.bounds];
grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
grayView.tag = TAG_GRAYVIEW; 

[button addSubview:grayView];

// remove the gray overlay
UIView *grayView = [button viewWithTag:TAG_GRAYVIEW];
[grayView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Would you use `UIResponder`'s  `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to add the overlay and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to remove the overlay?

Comment: @JoJo that should work just fine, as it calls on the main thread.

Comment: This is so simple and works so well! I just used it on a UIImageView, beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a semi transperant grey image PNG file. You need to then set Image of button in `Highlighted` state.

Also note that both the images for `Normal` State and `Highlighted` State need to have the images with titles on them.

As once we set the image to button, `btn.titleLabel.text` won't be displayed.

So you can have a **image with transperant background and title on it** for `Normal` state. And an **grey image with title on it** for `Highlighted` State.

Code for doing it programmatically is

```
[btn setImage:@"Transperant.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:@"Grey.png" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @JoJo: Please refer to my answer. I think that is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button up something like this.
*mind you I didn't create the image for this example.

Set your button type to custom, and in "State Config" select "Highlighted" from there you will want to set the image of the button to be a semi-transparent grey image. There are probably several other ways to achieve this same effect but this one should be nice and simple.

[image]

Comment: I will not be using Interface Builder. My views will be dynamically generated with code.

Answer (score 0):

The default `UIButton` masks the opaque content using a gray highlight. For example when using a transparent png, only the parts that contain non-transparent pixels will be grayed out on touch. The default `UIButton` highlight has no effect on subviews/sublayers, and will only work on provided images. What you see in the Facebook app is probably just a UIWebView highlight, possibly customized using css.

To create something similar using your own control (to prevent the overhead of a `UIWebView`) you should probably create your own `UIControl` subclass and highlight the content on touch using a transparent `CALayer`. You can even mask the `CALayer` to only highlight the actual contents, instead of a rectangular shape.

Also see my stackoverflow post on [creating custom controls for iOS by subclassing UIControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651516/474896).