# Is Quartz 2D useful to create custom views?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, quartz-2d

Is Quartz 2D a good choice to create custom views? Is there any other choices?

Thanks

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this question without knowing your use case. You should describe what you are trying to achieve. A "good choice" requires a little more background.

Comment: Ok, and sorry.
I want to make my app's UI as Evernote UI : works as Layers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! 
This is the standard way to go.
(See also ios View Programming Guide, chapter [Custom View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23))

I have done all my custom Views using `Quartz2D/Core Graphics` in `UIView::drawRect()`
(A compass rose, rulers, a custom user location for MkapView) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on what you want to do. It is perfectly fine to do 2d drawing, but you could use images just as well. I prefer using `CALayer` for simple effects myself.

I posted an answer on [creating custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651516/474896) and the several options to draw a control to a different question, but it applies here as well.

Comment: I think of making 'stacked' layout : as Evernote5